# ForEach within List: Benefit of the pattern?

Tags: swift, swiftui

For example:

```
List {
    ForEach(models) { element in 
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

**Why is a ForEach wrapped within a List? What's the benefit of that pattern?**

Why not using `List(models) { ... }` alone and no ForEach at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can have some non-repeating elements before and after the `ForEach` but keeping them inside the `list`, so you can use list functionalities like edit, delete, swipe, reorder, row style and etc on them.